# How to pass testng Dataprovider first set parameters to first test and second set Paramater to second test ans so on

Tags: testng

Here is my code, i want to pass first set data {"shankar","admin123"} to only test1() 
and second set data {"Siva","admin@123"} to test2(), 
please help me on that i have tried @ factory also...please help me guys.

```
package com.vmetry.dataprovider;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DataProviderTest {


    @Test(dataProvider="dp")
    public void test1(String uname, String pass){
        System.out.println("the test1 param are: "+uname+"-"+pass);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="dp")
    public void test2(String uname, String pass){
        System.out.println("the test1 param are: "+uname+"-"+pass);
    }

    //passing data provider data
    @DataProvider(name="dp")
    public Object[][] data(){
        Object[][] obj={{"Vasanth","admin123"},{"Shanmugam","admin@123"}};
        return obj;

    }
}
```

****************************ACTUALLY THIS IS MY CASE************************
[Please CLICK THE IMAGE TO KNOW MY SCENARIO REQUIREMENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwSbL.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

In your example you do not need to use `DataProvider` at all:

```java
public class DataProviderTest {
    @Test
    public void test1(){
        String uname="Shanmugam";
        String pass="admin123";
        System.out.println("the test1 param are: "+uname+"-"+pass);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        String uname="Shanmugam";
        String pass="admin@123";
        System.out.println("the test1 param are: "+uname+"-"+pass);
    }
}
```

If for some odd reason you *must* use a `DataProvider` then you can create additional ones that filter your original one:

```java
public class DataProviderTest {
    @Test(dataProvider="dp1")
    public void test1(String uname, String pass){
        System.out.println("the test1 param are: "+uname+"-"+pass);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="dp2")
    public void test2(String uname, String pass){
        System.out.println("the test1 param are: "+uname+"-"+pass);
    }

    @DataProvider(name="dp1", indices={0})
    public Object[][] data(){
        return data()
    }

    @DataProvider(name="dp2", indices={1})
    public Object[][] data(){
        return data()
    }

    @DataProvider(name="dp")
    public Object[][] data(){
        return new Object[][]{{"Vasanth","admin123"},{"Shanmugam","admin@123"}};
    }
}
```

Or if you want one test class per data provider record with your test(s):

```java
public class DataProviderTest {
    private final String uname;
    private final String pass;

    @Factory(dataProvider="dp")
    public DataProviderTest(String uname, String pass) {
        this.uname=uname;
        this.pass=pass;
    }

    @DataProvider(name="dp")
    public static Object[][] data() {
        return new Object[][]{{"Vasanth","admin123"},{"Shanmugam","admin@123"}};
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("the test1 param are: "+uname+"-"+pass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mfulton26, actually ur answer is helpful, but my scenario is am reading rows of data from dynamic excel through object[][] and providing via dataprovider, so can i pass data as one dataset to first test & second data set to second test using Constructor & @ Factory, or anything, because i dont want to mention data provider for each test. Can you help m on this please.

Comment: @vasanths I'm not sure I understand correctly or not: Are you saying you want one test class per record in your data provider?

Comment: not like that as u given the abov answer is fine for me but only thing i dont want to mention dataprovider for each test is it possible to pass from central dataprovider(i.e my requirement is  that i want to use atmost only one data provider alone, thanks in advance

Comment: Please CLICK THE IMAGE TO KNOW MY SCENARIO REQUIREMENT, kindly help in that

Comment: @vasanths, if the test does the same thing then the factory example above will do the job. Otherwise I do not believe TestNG provides tooling for this but you can easily get the appropriate `uname` and `pass` on your own within a TestNG test method by managing the data yourself.

Comment: Yes mfulton26, thanks for your answers, we know that @factory will initialize constructor paramater, so same data set will passed to test1 & Test2 and so on, but my company is wanted me to try for this scenario.

Comment: @vasanths The same data set will _NOT_ be passed to test1 & test2 and so on, each test class will get its own record from your data-provider.